# Bean validation with no effects

Tags: jsf-2, bean-validation

After having introduced the validation when I click on "save" in my page, nothing happens.
In the page I have "save" and "cancel". I put "immediate=true" to cancel button, so that no validation is performed and it returns to the previous view as supposed.
When I click on save, the validation is performed and the errors are correctly displayed, but if/when I enter the correct input (so that the validation gives no errors), instead of processing the data and returning to the previous page, nothing happens...

Do I miss something?

Here some code snippets:

View:

```
<f:metadata>
  <f:viewParam name="mode" value="#{roomDetailController.model.mode}"/>
  <f:viewParam name="dbId" value="#{roomDetailController.model.dbId}"/>

  <f:event listener="#{roomDetailController.processCommand}" type="preRenderView"/>
</f:metadata>

...

<tr>
  <td>
    <h:outputLabel value="#{msg.roomFormFieldRoomName}:"/>
  </td>
  <td>
    <h:inputText id="roomName" value="#{detailModel.afterObject.roomName}" disabled="#{detailModel.mode == detailModel.viewMode}">
      <f:validateBean/>
    </h:inputText>
    <h:message for="roomName" style="color:red"/><br/>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <h:outputLabel value="#{msg.roomFormFieldRoomIPs}:"/>
  </td>
  <td>
    <h:inputText id="roomIPs" value="#{detailModel.afterObject.roomIPs}" disabled="#{detailModel.mode == detailModel.viewMode}">
      <f:validateBean/>
    </h:inputText>
    <h:message for="roomIPs" style="color:red"/><br/>
  </td>
</tr>

...

<!-- SUBMIT BUTTON -->
<h:commandButton
  styleClass     = "waiButton"
  value          = "#{commonButtonSubmit}"
  action         = "#{detailController.submitAction()}"
  rendered       = "#{detailModel.mode != detailModel.viewMode}"
/>

<!-- CANCEL BUTTON -->
<h:commandButton
  styleClass = "waiButton"
  value      = "#{commonButtonCancel}"
  action     = "#{detailController.cancelAction()}"
  immediate  = "true"
  rendered   = "#{detailModel.mode == detailModel.cancelMode or detailModel.mode == detailModel.editMode or detailModel.mode == detailModel.multiEditMode or detailModel.mode == detailModel.createMode}"
/>
...
```

Controller:

```
...
// Action: "submit" clicked
public String submitAction()
{
  detailModel.setCommand( DetailModel.Command.SUBMIT );
  return null;
}

// Action: "cancel" clicked
public String cancelAction()
{
  if ( detailModel.getEditMode().equals( detailModel.getMode() ) )
  {
    detailModel.setMode( detailModel.getViewMode() );
    return null;
  }
  else
  {
    // Multi Edit Mode
    return appendUrlParameter( getListViewName(), FACES_REDIRECT_TRUE );
  }
}
...
```

If you need some more info, let me know...

Comment: Sorry, I think the problem has nothing to do with the validation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. As said it had nothing to do with the validation.